# Get entire model in Backbone JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-model

In backbone javascript models, we get individual items as shown below:

```
var type = this.model.get("type");
```

Here, type will be defined in server side & then fetched in JS using above syntax.

My question is how do I get the entire model in one shot?

I tried `this.model.toString()` but it prints `[object object]`

Any suggestion?

EDIT: I'm using above line of code in backbone view & not the model. And in this view, I need to read all the models data even if its JSON string, thts fine with me. How do I get it. I don't want to use separate collection or anything else. I need to update the above view only to get entire model.

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do. To see the model attributes,`this.model.attributes`. Is this that you want?

Comment: Thanks go-oleg. I found the answer in the link you proivided. Please put it as answer & I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`model.toJSON()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) to get all the attributes of a model.

Answer (score 0):

you use a collection

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection

You can then iterate though the collection to obtain each model.

```
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Book
});
```

for example and then

```
books = new Library();
books.each(function(book) {
  book.publish();
});
```

to iterate

Comment: I updated my question. I need the details in the view itself without using any new collection.

Comment: Why use backbone at all if you want to use it like that ?